# Angular 2 Observable Issue Duplicates, not updating results

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2, rxjs

Im working on an Ionic2 app basically built with angular 2. Im having a problem with the following observable that returns all the users that are close by.. sometimes when I navigate away from the view and then back it doubles the users by repeating data or other times it only shows 1 result and doesnt update the view when another user logs in, I cant seem to figure out what the issue is but its an essential piece of the app so I really need it to be solid.

Service.ts

```
    @Injectable()
    export class LocationTracker {


    public nearme = <[IuserGeoLocation]>[];

    public firebaseRef: any;
    public geoFire: any;
    public space: Subject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(0);



    constructor( public zone: NgZone, public fire:Fb, public user:User) {
        this.fb          = fire.instance().database();
        this.firebaseRef = this.fb.ref('geofire');
        this.geoFire     = new GeoFire(this.firebaseRef);
    }





        UsersNearME() : Observable<any> {

        this.nearme.length = 0;

            let geoQuery = this.geoFire.query({
            center: [this.lat, this.lng],
            radius: 4.609 //kilometers
            });
            geoQuery.on("key_entered", (key, location, distance) => {

        const sender = this.fb.ref('/users/'+ key  );
            sender.on('value',  (snapshot) => {
                const profile = snapshot.val().profile;
                this.nearme.push({ 
                    userid: key,
                    userloc: location,
                    userdistance: distance.toFixed(2),
                    email: profile.email,
                    name: profile.displayName || 'Anonymous',
                    image: profile.photoURL || ''
                });
                this.space.next(this.nearme);
            }); 
            // console.log("User near you  " + key + " found at " + location + " (" + distance + " km away)");
            });

        return this.space.asObservable();
        }






    }
```

Component.ts

```
    public usersNearMe;

    constructor( public locationTracker: LocationTracker ) {
            this.zone.run(() => { 
                 this.usersNearMe = this.locationTracker.UsersNearME();
            });
    }
```

component.html

```
    <ion-content padding>
    <!--       <ion-col class="member-item"  (click)="viewUser(member.profile.uid)" width-33 *ngFor="let member of members | async; let i = index" [ngClass]="{ hideme : activeUser === member?.profile.uid }"> -->
    <ion-grid>
        <ion-row class="member-group" >
            <ion-col class="member-item"  tappable  width-33 *ngFor="let m of usersNearMe | async; let i = index">
            {{ m?.userid }}
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
    </ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your component isn't really set up correctly:

Component:

```
export class YourComponent implements ngOnInit {
    public usersNearMe;

    constructor( private locationTracker: LocationTracker ) {}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.locationTracker.UsersNearME.subscribe(data => {
            this.usersNearMe = data;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Using subscribe wont allow me to use async in the ngfor though

Comment: @REPTILE see how this approach fares without the async pipe.

Comment: Yeah it works but is it in real time :) I kind of wanted it to update in realtime as people come into your location but I guess il have to sacrifice it.

Comment: Usually when you receive update from Observable you should call cd.DetectChanges from ChangeDetectorRef in your subscribe handler.